# about 2-sylow subgroups of group of the form $G \times H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

suppose $G$ and $H$ are finite groups,consider the group $G \times H$ ,and suppose $G_1$ is 2-sylow subgroup of $G$ and $H_1$ is 2-sylow subgroup of $H$ ,

1. does $ G_1 \times H_1$ is 2-sylow subgroup of $G \times H$ ?
2. do all 2-sylow subgroups of $G \times H$ are the form $G_1 \times H_1$ ?
3. if one of $G$ or $H$ ,or both of them don't have 2-sylow subgroups ,does $G \times H$ have any 2-sylow subgroups ?

for 1 and 2 my guess is yes,by definition of 2-sylow subgroups; but I thought that maybe there is a counterexample.

for 3 my guess is no,but I have no Idea how.

by the construction of $G \times H$ this answers came to my mind at the first place but then I filled with doubts.

this three questions is important for the project I am working,so it will be great if you help me or giving me references to study subjects like this,thanks a lot.

Comment: Both the first ones are true. The second follows from Sylow subgroups being conjugate. The third one is easy to check straight from the definition.

Comment: Every finite group has Sylow subgroups for every prime.  By "has no $2$-Sylow subgroups" do you just mean that the $2$-Sylow subgroups are trivial?

Comment: If both $G$ and $H$ have trivial $p$-Sylow subgroups then $G \times H$ has trivial $p$-Sylow subgroup as well.  If *either* $G$ or $H$ has a nontrivial $p$-Sylow subgroup then $G \times H$ has a nontrivial $p$-Sylow subgroup as well.

Comment: @Jim ,yes I mean that trivial 2-sylow subgroups.thanks a lot.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, thanks a lot .